# Simple PHP server - authenticate incoming queries/commands

Tags: php, authentication, encryption

I'm developing an application composed of two elements: a simple PHP server interacting with a SQL DB and a client which on certain events will send information to the server to log.

I would like a way to somehow verify (on the server's side) that the incoming query is indeed coming from my client, because there is a possibilty that someone will decompile the client file and see how I connect and send commands to the server, and that would let them inject false data.

I have no idea how to do such a mechanism though simply because anything I implement in the client could (theoretically) be viewed after decompilation process. Or maybe obfuscation is a solution in this case?

Comment: What you want is not possible: If the client contains the information necessary to authenticat, an attacker is able to extract it!

Comment: That's precisely why I'm asking the question: maybe there is a better way to achieve what I want? I'm not insitsting on "authentication"; I just want to block false queries.

Comment: "Blocking false queries" are just other word for "blocking unauthorized access" - both have the same weakness: If the client contains **all** parts of the puzzle, a dedicated attacker can extract them. This is not a question of implementation, its a systemic problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is intrepid enough to decompile your client, they will simply write their own client using your mechanism and there's no way you can distinguish the two.  No amount of "authentication" will stop that.  (Like for example, if someone gets my private SSH key, game over: they are me until those keys are revoked.)

The best you can do is make it hard for them to decompile, detect intrusion, and limit damage.  Some ideas, but you really should consider the [attack patterns you expect to face](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_patterns):

- Only allow the client to execute certain commands with certain parameters
- Do not allow any more than the expected number of commands per time period
- Limit the IP from which those certain commands can come
- Be able to revoke client privileges on the server

PS: Expect this question to be closed or at least downvoted.  It's not about code, but about design.

Comment: Thank you :). Well, I didn't expect this kind of reaction. Don't want to sound "smart", but programming is about design as well (in fact, mostly) isn't it?

Comment: I agree totally. Just SO wants questions with objective answers that are provably correct for the stated problem.  With a subjective question, there will be opinion answers that simply aren't provably correct.  I personally think these kinds of questions should stand, but I'm not a mod.  Good luck!